# Inverse sin function only returns 0

Tags: c, xna

When I run this code, it only returns 0, why is that?

> var test = Math.Asin(3 / 4);

Comment: Integer math. 3/4 = 0 remainder 3 == 0. ASin(0)= 0. Try asin(3.0/ 4.0)

Comment: Do you mean like this? `var test = Math.Asin(3.0/4.0)` It still returns 0

Comment: Hmm. That is what I meant. Now I am stumped.

Comment: What happens when you do this?  var test = Math.Asin(0.75);

Answer (score 0):

It is because you use 3/4, the program will understand that they are both integer. The result of (integer) 3 / (integer) 4 is 0. Therefore, the result of `Math.Asin(3/4) = Math.Asin(0) = 0`.

If you want to gain the result of Math.Asin(0.75f), you should use `Math.Asin((double)3/4)` or `Math.Asin(3.0f/4.0f)`, or whatever formatting that has floating point. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please note that `(double)(3/4)` will calculate `3/4` in integer math and only cast the resulting 0 to `double`, resulting in a `double 0` as well.

Comment: Thank you @NicoSchertler, I fixed it :)